# What is the proper way to detect if unit tests are running at runtime in Xcode?

Tags: objective-c, ocunit, xctest

When I'm running unit tests, I'd like to skip some code (e.g. I don't want `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:..]` to run). I'm looking for a runtime check if I'm currently running units tests or not.

I know I have seen code that checks the Objective-C runtime if unit tests are running but am not able to find it anymore.

Comment: Check [this](http://www.innovaptor.com/blog/2013/09/02/xcode-preprocessor-macros-for-test-code.html)

Comment: This is what mock is for.

Answer (score 17):

You can use [this method](https://code.google.com/p/google-toolbox-for-mac/source/browse/trunk/UnitTesting/GTMFoundationUnitTestingUtilities.m#26) from [google-toolbox-for-mac](https://code.google.com/p/google-toolbox-for-mac/)

```
// Returns YES if we are currently being unittested.
+ (BOOL)areWeBeingUnitTested {
  BOOL answer = NO;
  Class testProbeClass;
#if GTM_USING_XCTEST // you may need to change this to reflect which framework are you using
  testProbeClass = NSClassFromString(@"XCTestProbe");
#else
  testProbeClass = NSClassFromString(@"SenTestProbe");
#endif
  if (testProbeClass != Nil) {
    // Doing this little dance so we don't actually have to link
    // SenTestingKit in
    SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(@"isTesting");
    NSMethodSignature *sig = [testProbeClass methodSignatureForSelector:selector];
    NSInvocation *invocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:sig];
    [invocation setSelector:selector];
    [invocation invokeWithTarget:testProbeClass];
    [invocation getReturnValue:&answer];
  }
  return answer;
}
```

The reason that `NSClassFromString` and `NSInvocation` are used is to allow code compile without linking to xctest or ocunit

Comment: Works for iOS as well

Comment: I would suggest using `[testProbeClass valueForKey:@"isTesting"];` to avoid `NSInvocation`.

Answer (score 13):

Rather that sprinkling "am I testing?" conditionals throughout production code, I isolate the check to one place: `main`. There, I check for an *alternate* application delegate for testing. If it's available, I use it instead of the the regular application delegate. This completely bypasses the regular launch sequence:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        Class appDelegateClass = NSClassFromString(@"TestingAppDelegate");
        if (!appDelegateClass)
            appDelegateClass = [AppDelegate class];
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass(appDelegateClass));
    }
}
```

You can read more about this technique here: [How to Easily Switch Your iOS App Delegate for Testing](https://qualitycoding.org/ios-app-delegate-testing/)

Answer (score 12):

Select the project, and then the test target:

[image]

Select Build Settings and choose All and Combined. Type 'preproc' in the search box - you're after Preprocessor Macros.

[image]

Add a macro to the Debug configuration called `TEST` and set it equal to `1`:

[image]

Then in your code, you can do this:

```
#ifndef TEST
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] doEvilThingForTesting];
#endif
```

Or if you have code that you want to *only* run in a test environment:

```
#ifdef TEST
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] doAwesomeTestOnlyThing];
#endif
```

It's not exactly *runtime*, but the unit tester compiles the code before it runs the tests IIRC, so it should be the same effect - you're essentially modifying the code right before running the tests.

Comment: it works but it is also restricted to code compiled with tests, for instance the target application code is not affected (i.e. your app delegate has the macro not defined). My way to solve this was to duplicate DEBUG configuration and set the macro there as well and then edited my scheme to use this new configuration when testing.

Answer (score 9):

I'm not sure how long this will continue to work, but it works for me right now with Version 9.0 beta 6 (9M214v).

```
let isTesting = { () -> Bool in
    if let _ = ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment["XCTestConfigurationFilePath"] {
        return true
    } else if let testingEnv = ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment["DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES"] {
        return testingEnv.contains("libXCTTargetBootstrapInject.dylib")
    } else {
        return false
    }
}()
```

No build environment or scheme changes are necessary.

It appears that there are two different environment variables in play depending on whether you are running a single test case or the entire test suite. Also, the variable value also differs depending whether or not you are running in simulator or on a real device.

Comment: FYI, this no longer works using Xcode Version 12.0 beta 1 (12A6159).

Comment: In Xcode 14.2 I see the following keys in environment to indicate the code is running in a unit test: `XCInjectBundleInto`, `XCTestSessionIdentifier` and `XCTestBundlePath`

Answer (score 6):

I think you can check like this for Xcode 7.3

```
-(BOOL) isRunningUnitTests
{
    NSDictionary* environment = [ [ NSProcessInfo processInfo ] environment ];
    NSString* theTestConfigPath = environment[ @"XCTestConfigurationFilePath" ];
    return theTestConfigPath != nil;
}
```

Comment: nope... Not working on xcode 7.3 and also on xcode 8

Answer (score 2):

The easiest (and working in Xcode 7 with XCTest!) way to check is to have a look at the process info for a matching `xctest` bundle:

```
static BOOL isRunningTests(void)
{
    NSDictionary* environment = [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] environment];
    NSString* injectBundle = environment[@"XCInjectBundle"];
    return [[injectBundle pathExtension] isEqualToString:@"xctest"];
}
```

Source: https://www.objc.io/issues/1-view-controllers/testing-view-controllers/#integration-with-xcode

Comment: In Xcode 14.2, I see `XCInjectBundleInto` (not `XCInjectBundle`). There's also `XCTestSessionIdentifier` which seems a bit clearer for detecting unit tests.

Answer (score 2):

Just use this:

```c
+ (BOOL)isUnitTestRunning
{
    Class testProbeClass;
    testProbeClass = NSClassFromString(@"XCTestProbe");
    return (testProbeClass != nil);
}
```

Comment: Some additional context or explanation would be helpful to explain why this answer is the best solution.